# Hyphen-delimited values and LEFT_JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row with some values hyphen-delimited:

**table: live_customers**
**row: areas**

```
id | areas
 1 | 10-20-30
 2 | 40-50-60
...
```

Using this...

```
LEFT JOIN $table5 AS table5 ON live.areas REGEXP CONCAT('(^|-) ?',table5.id,' ?($|-)')
```

My results looks like:

```
(tab id:1) area: 10
(tab id:1) area: 20
...
(tab id:2) area: 40
...
```

But i expect:

```
(tab id:1) area: 10,20,30
(tab id:2) area: 40,50,60
```

How could i solve that?

EDIT:

The full query looks like:

```
SELECT live.*,
live.id AS lid,
table1.id, table1.value AS tn_val,
table2.id, table2.value AS tp_val,
table3.id, table3.value AS ht_val,
table5.id, table5.value AS ar_val
FROM $dblist AS live
LEFT JOIN $table1 AS table1 ON live.town = table1.id
LEFT JOIN $table2 AS table2 ON live.htype = table2.id
LEFT JOIN $table3 AS table3 ON live.ht = table3.id
LEFT JOIN $table5 AS table5 ON live.areas REGEXP CONCAT('(^|-) ?',table5.id,' ?($|-)')
ORDER BY live.id ASC
```

PHP echoes:

```
...
if ($post['areas']){ // Debugging areas stuff
echo '<strong>'.$_areas.': (ar_val)</strong> '.$post['ar_val'].'<p>';
echo '<strong>'.$_areas.': (areas)</strong> '.$post['areas'].'<p>';
}
...
```

EDIT2:

It's quite hard for me to explain my issue in English, but i'm trying the best i can :)

in the table "live_customers" i does have this:

```
id | areas
 1 | 10-20-30
 2 | 40-50-60
...
```

in the table "areas" (that is a completely different table):

```
id | value
38 | Zone1
39 | Zone2
40 | Zone3
...
```

In the SQL query you see just tables variables because i previousvly declared them at the top of page:

```
$table5 = 'areas';
$dblist = 'live_customers';
```

etc..

**Solution**

Thanks anyone for their answers and for let me know "GROUP_CONCAT".

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT live.*,
live.id AS lid,
table1.id, table1.value AS tn_val,
table2.id, table2.value AS tp_val,
table3.id, table3.value AS ht_val,
table5.id, GROUP_CONCAT(table5.value) AS ar_val
FROM $dblist AS live
LEFT JOIN $table1 AS table1 ON live.town = table1.id
LEFT JOIN $table2 AS table2 ON live.htype = table2.id
LEFT JOIN $table3 AS table3 ON live.ht = table3.id
LEFT JOIN $table5 AS table5 ON FIND_IN_SET(table5.id, REPLACE(live.areas, '-', ','))
GROUP BY live.id
```

Result is what i expected ^^

Comment: Using a `GROUP_CONCAT()`, most likely.  Please post the rest of your query and we can help you to incorporate it.

Comment: I don't see any column in there resembling `areas`. Which column are you trying to list? It would help to see the actual table & column ames, rather than PHP variables.

Comment: Tried with GROUP_CONCAT() but doesn't work.

Comment: If you post the column names you are actually working with, we can help more easily. GROUP_CONCAT() is an aggregate function and therefore requires a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It's quite hard for me to explain my issue in English, but i'm trying the best i can :)

in the table "live_customers" i does have this:

id | areas
 1 | 10-20-30
 2 | 40-50-60
...

in the table "areas" (that is a completely different table):

id | value
38 | Zone1
39 | Zone2
40 | Zone3
...

In the SQL query you see just tables variables because i previousvly declared them at the top of page:

$table5 = 'areas';
$dblist = 'live_customers';
etc..

Answer (score 0):

Take it together with GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 0):

First thing to say is that your schema violates First Normal Form (1NF) in that the column areas is not atomic. You should not be putting 3 different values in one column.

Next you say you have a table called live_customers with a row called areas. This is nonsense. Rows do not have names, columns do. You show a bit of table with 2 columns id and areas. What table is this?

Next in the query there is no mention of a table called live_customers.

Next, if there is a column called areas in the table with the alias of live, then the output should contain that column since you are selecting live.*. That being the case, your results cannot be what you showed us, since it would contain a results column with data like 10-20-30

Finally those cannot be the results of the posted query since I can see a results column of lid specified.

If you would care to take some time over ensuring that the questionyou post makes sense, then you might get a reasonable answer.